# Doctrine 2 + Zend 2 - Same entity mappings for different modules

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have configured doctrine in my zf2 project, and I have my entity mappings for my database in one module. Until here orm:validate-schema was working.

But when I try to create Individual entity mappings for some specific db tables in another module (that was also mapped on the principal module) The schema validation throws a OK for mappings but a SchemaException saying that the table with name XXX.xxx already exists.

This could be because the same table entity was mapped on an already mapped module? How can I have specific entities for individual modules?

Thanks!